# Button alignment disrupted

Tags: html, css, button, alignment

Button alignment is disrupted when I'm trying to use img tag inside button tags

```
<div class="con"><button>A</button><button>B</button><button>C</button><button><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Cyhm06w.gif"></button><button>E</button></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tzawojdj/2/
and things get even worth when I leave button tag empty
http://jsfiddle.net/tzawojdj/3/

what causes such behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Add `vertical-align:bottom;` to your `button` style